# how to make a nice table of content in html like this one

Tags: html

Any one can look at this and guess how this nice toc was created in HTML?

Do you think it was done by hand, or a software was used to make it?

http://diveintohtml5.info/table-of-contents.html

view source did not give me much of a hint. I am newbie in HTML.

Comment: it's really simple to make it by hand i don't think that is too hard for code but +1 for good concept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple, he is using a dotted background for `li` element which is than covered by text wrapped in another element for example I'm wrapping inside a `span` here with white background

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6FtaQ/)

CSS

```
li {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(http://diveintohtml5.info/i/dot.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 10px;
}

li span {
    background: white;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```